# How to create a Layout for a custom view in SugarCRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I have created a fully custom view, I want this view to only show certain fields in an editview format so I can update records. But this view is to be different from the normal editview. How do I add a custom metadata file to this view that will allow me to define the form and fields that I need? The view is tied to a custom button and currently just shows "works". This is working so far just need to understand how to define the layout.

the controller:

```
if(!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

class CustomCasesController extends SugarController {

function action_resolve_Case() {
    $this->view = 'resolve_case';
}

}
```

The view :

```
if (!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry)
die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

require_once('include/MVC/View/SugarView.php');


class CasesViewresolve_case extends SugarView {

public function CasesViewresolve_case() {
    parent::SugarView();
}

function preDisplay() {

    parent::preDisplay();

}

public function display() {

   // include ('test.php');

    echo "works";
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old, but still may help someone...

You can :

1. work inside the display function. Everything you do or echo here will be shown inside the main Sugar app screen (navbar, footer, etc) so it will look native.
2. Work directly inside the controller and echo everything out.

Build your form with the fields you want to edit and have as action a function in controller where you can use the bean->save() method for the POST results.

`<form name="whatever" method="POST" action="index.php?module=Contacts&action=yourcustomaction">`

ex:

```
    `$contact = new Contact();
     $contact->retrieve("{$_REQUEST['contactId']}"); 
     //be sure to send the id in the button/link to the view
     $contact->first_name =$_POST['first_name'];
     $contact->last_name =$_POST['last_name'];
     .....
     $contact->save();`
```

Not very elegant but the only other option I know of is working with smarty templates which I'm not familiar with.

If anybody has a better solution, please post it.